# how to set the width of output in lst file in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

I use `display` to output results of some variables. As shown below, variable values are list in one line. With more months included, results go to right and do not come back. It's inconvenient to check. I set the value of page width, but it seems the parameter is not for this. So my question is which is the right parameter I should use to set. Thanks.

[image]

Actually I set page width as 72 in GAMS IDE (options -> output) before I post it here. But it does not work. Now I tried to set pagewidth in command line from GAMS terminal (GAMS studio -> tool -> terminal). This is my command: gams myfile PW=80. I cannot see the setting after "-- GAMS parameter defined". I'm not sure if I set it in the wrong way.

I didn't find this page width issue in an old GAMS version. I'm using GAMS 32, and it becomes a problem.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: PageWidth (https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_GamsCall.html#GAMSAOpagewidth) should actually be the right thing to set. Can you see in the log (after "--- GAMS Parameters defined") that it was set to the value you want?

Comment: I tried to add PW in command line, but it seems not working.

Comment: Could you share the start of your log, that shows the parameter used by GAMS?

Comment: It's added, the command is "gams base_runfile PW=80"

Comment: That's odd. Could be some kind of error in the system. Maybe it would be best to contact GAMS support (https://www.gams.com/support/) about this.

Comment: yeah, I feel so. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like "-pw 80" as argument in the command line.

Comment: I tried to add pw in command line, but it does not work. It's odd.